# Foreign Key Constraint issue code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to use code first to create a parent-child relationship for a Collection class, however I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 
>   FK.dbo.subcollect.dbo.collection_subcollectionID on table 'subcollect'
>   may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

I thought that adding 'WillCascadeOnDelete(false)' would fix this issue however this hasn't worked. I have the feeling that this has something to do with the circular references but I'm not sure...

The main collection class:

```
public class Collection
{
    public int CollectionID { get; private set; }    

    public ICollection<SubCollect> SubCollects { get; private set; }
}
```

The subcollect class:

```
public class SubCollect
{
    public int SubCollectID { get; private set; }

    public int? ParentCollectionID { get; private set; }
    public Collection ParentCollection { get; private set; }

    public int? SubCollectionID { get; private set; }
    public Collection SubCollection { get; private set; }

    public bool IsFeatured { get; private set; }
    public int Position { get; private set; }
}
```

This is the configuration class:

```
public class SubCollectConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<SubCollect>
{
    public SubCollectConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasRequired(c => c.ParentCollection)
           .WithMany(c => c.SubCollects)
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCollectionID)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.HasRequired(c => c.SubCollection)
                               .WithMany()
                               .HasForeignKey( c => c.SubCollectionID)
                                  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the answer, but your `SubCollect` foreign keys are not consistent with your configuration class. You have made `ParentCollection` and `SubCollection` required using FluentAPI, but the foreign keys are nullable integers, suggesting the relationships are optional.

Comment: Which version of EF you are using? Is there something omitted from the example. This example as is works with EF 6.1.